# How to building a linux executable in CentOS 5 and running it on RedHat 9?

Tags: linux, gcc

We had just migrated our software to CentOS 5 platform, from RedHat 9.
We're now compiling our C programs on CentOS 5 using gcc v4.1.2 and everything works fine on CentOS, but these new binaries will not run on RedHat 9 anymore (kernel 2.4.1). 
Any suggestions on how we can compile a binary that can run on both of these platforms?

Answer (score 1):

Try mock. See http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Projects/Mock and https://fedorahosted.org/mock/ or just install CentOS' mock package and add an F9 config for it.

Caution: F9 has not been supported in years.